# How to keep the wanted values in a select and remove remaining using jquery?

Tags: jquery, select

I have an function where I have some drop-downs.

I have some values where I have to check whether the values exist in the dropdown.
If they exist I have to keep them and remove other options from my dropdown

This is what I have been trying to do

```
function getimage(value, ProdId) {
  $.getJSON("/api/ProductDetails", { option: value, productid: ProdId }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (idx, product) {
      $('#defaultimage').empty();
      $('<img id="dfltimage"/>').attr({ src: product.ImageURL }).appendTo('#defaultimage');

      if (product.options.length > 0) {
        $.each(product.options, function (idx, option) {
          /*appending the each option to a label*/
          $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + "").empty();
          if (option.values.length > 0) {
            /*Creating a select tag for the Retrieved options*/
            //$("" + "#" + options.OptionName + "").empty();                  
            $.each(option.values, function (idx, value) {                 
              alert(value.OptionValue);
 //             $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + "").append('<option value="' + value.OptionValue + '">' + value.OptionValue + '</option>');
              $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + "").children('option').hide();
  //            $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + "").children("option[text=" + value.OptionValue + "]").show();
              $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + "option[value='" + value.OptionValue + "']").show();
            });
          }
        })
      }
    });
  });
}
```

in this case dropdowns are empty in the end

this is what the changes i made from the answer given

```
           if (product.options.length > 0) {
                    $.each(product.options, function (idx, option) {
                        /*appending the each option to a label*/

                        $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + " option").attr('not_required', 'true');
                        if (option.values.length > 0) {
                            /*Creating a select tag for the Retrieved options*/                                    
                            $.each(option.values, function (idx, value) {                             
                            alert(value.OptionValue);
                            $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + "option[value='" + this_value + "']").removeAttr('not_required');
                            $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + " option[not_required=true]").remove();

                            });

                        }

                    })
                }
```

the values are not removed

Comment: The relevant part starts at `$.each(product.options,`...

Comment: The reason the options are empty is because you empty them with `$("" + "#" + option.OptionName + "").empty();`. then `if (option.values.length > 0)` will always return false, because each one is empty.

Comment: @bukko yes i noticed that what should i do in order to avoid that

Comment: Try doing it a different way, like my solution below...? That way you only remove the options you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by setting an attribute in all options, e.g. "not_required".

```
$('#my_select_id option').attr('not_required','true');
```

Then loop through your results, removing the attribute for each one as you find it.

```
for(...) {
  $('option[value=' + this_value + ']').removeAttr('not_required');
}
```

Finally select all options which still have the attribute and remove (or hide) them.

```
$('#my_select_id option[not_required=true]').remove();
```

[Edit]

You are removing the 'unwanted' options too soon. You need to wait until the loop finishes.

This is my version of your edit above:

```
       if (product.options.length > 0) {
                $.each(product.options, function (idx, option) {
                    $("" + "#" + option.OptionName + " option").attr('not_required', 'true');
                    if (option.values.length > 0) {
                        $.each(option.values, function (idx, value) {                             
                            alert(value.OptionValue);
                            $("#" + option.OptionName + " option[value='" + this_value + "']").removeAttr('not_required');
                        });
                    }
                })
                $("#" + option.OptionName + " option[not_required=true]").remove();
            }
```

Comment: the values are not removed here

Comment: Do any of the options have the 'not_required' attribute? If not, none of their values are being found in the loop at the beginning.

Comment: where are appedning the new values to the select

Comment: If you view the DOM using an editor (e.g. in Chrome) you should see the new `not_required` attribute. Of course you will only see this if the option has not been deleted, so comment out that line in the script to check up to that part.